# How can I check if there is new beta version of cocoa pods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am using cocoa pods, and currently i am using pre version 1.0.0.beta.6, which i installed couple of months ago. I would like to check if there is new version, but without installing that new version.

I was browsing here and there, but could not find command for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link :

https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoapods/versions

Here are listed all versions of CocoaPods

Also, you can try :

`gem list cocoapods --remote --all`

It will print all available versions of gem (without beta version).

Answer (score 2):

When you make pod update, cocoa show you and suggest the last version, and suggest install the beta (I recomend don't do it!), just like this:

[image]